# Changing the WSDL Path in Wildfly

Tags: web-services, wildfly

I migrated my application from JBoss 5.1.0 GA to WildFly 8.2.0. I am facing an issue while loading WSDL after migrating to WildFly.

In Jboss 5.1.0 my Jboss WSDL location was `http://localhost:8080/project-ear-project-ejb/ProjectService?wsdl` and my UI framework was build based on the given path.

Now after migrating to WildFly I am getting WSDL path as `http://localhost:8080/project-ejb/projectService/project?WSDL`. Here projectService is the servicename and project is the name attribute of the  `@Webservice` Annotation.

```
@WebService(name = "project", serviceName = "projectService").
```

I have seen some wildfly documentation, but I didn't find any documentation specific to the above case. Is there any way in wildlfy to change the WSDL address as per the above requirement.

Comment: This looks like you were deploying an EAR file before, but are now just deploying the EJB jar

Comment: Hi Steve, I found the solution for this issue, we need to add jboss-webservices.xml and configure the required path in the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add jboss-webservices.xml file in ejb module-META-INF and configure the required path in the xml. In the above case, the xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webservices xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee/jbossws-web-services_1_0.xsd"
version="1.1">
 <context-root>project-ear-project-ejb</context-root>
 <port-component>
 <ejb-name>ProjectService</ejb-name>
 <port-component-name>ProjectService</port-component-name>
 <port-component-uri>/ProjectService</port-component-uri>
 </port-component>
</webservices>
```